# How to save complete web page

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way to save complete web-page using WebDriver?

Currently I do getPageSource() and then put everything into html local file, but saved page is in not good shape (strange characters, no images, all elements offset down)

See below code that I use:

```
   @Test
   public void testSomeThing(){
     FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://google.com");
     String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
     writeInFile(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/target/logs/testPage.html", pageSource);
   }

   public static void writeInFile(String sFileName, String sTextToWrite){
         FileWriter outFile;
         General.sendComments("Write to file: " + sFileName);
         try {
                outFile = new FileWriter(sFileName);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
                out.print(sTextToWrite);
                out.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }
```

Could somebody please suggest me the way I can save complete web page in firefox using WebDriver? e.g automatically?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Wouldn't a screen shot work instead?

Comment: On test case fail I want to save complete page , to investigate fail reasons. Page screen shot can't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange characters might have something to do with the encoding of the written file.

The other problems will probably have to do with the fact that you are loading a static html file for which the relative url's no longer point to anything.  Any javascript, css and image files will be missing.

Comment: Ok, but maybe somebody knows some Java lib that allows to do that?

Answer (score -3):

[Savw webPage to a file](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/SaveWebpagetoafile.htm)
Try it. but i didn't checked this