# Java Webdriver: How to save the page same as "save page as" in firefox?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Similar question asked below

[How to save complete web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118323/how-to-save-complete-web-page)

But there is no answer yet. The expected result is to get many files, some file to store image, etc.

I used the following,it will pop up a windows saying to save the file

```
val a=new FirefoxDriver()
a.get("http://www.baidu.com")
val b=new Actions(a)
b.action.keyDown(Keys.ALT).keyDown(Keys.F4).keyUp(Keys.ALT).perform();
```

But then how to click the save button? The following doesn't work

```
b.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use Robot utility in Java to handle this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.baidu.com/");

Robot robot = new Robot();

// press Ctrl+S the Robot's way
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);

Thread.sleep(2000L);

// press Enter
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

To use Robot utility you have to import following Java utilities:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

Comment: anything for .NET?

Comment: @Toolkit Please have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410015/java-robot-class-eqivalent-code-in-c-sharp

Answer (score -2):

When you use Robot utility the x axis and y axis has to be metioned appropriately however it will differ system to system instead we can use AUTO IT. 
You can refer here http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/forum/9-example-scripts/